# decision making in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
private Object artikanID(String string) {

        try {

            DAOTerjemah dao = new DAOTerjemah(ConnectionDB.getConnection()) {};
            List<Kata> terjemahan1 = new ArrayList<Kata>();
            List<Kata> terjemahan2 = new ArrayList<Kata>();
            List<Kata> terjemahan3 = new ArrayList<Kata>();

            terjemahan1 = dao.getByIndo(string);
            terjemahan2 = dao.getByIndo(string.substring(0,string.length()-1));
            terjemahan3 = dao.getByIndo(string.substring(0,string.length()-2));

            if (terjemahan1 == null) {
                return terjemahan1.get(0).getDayak();
            }            
            else {
                return terjemahan2.get(0).getDayak();
            }     
        }catch(Exception e){
            return string ;
        }
    }
```

there are 3 conditions(terjemahan1,terjemahan2 & terjemahan 3),
how to create the conditions to be executed terjemahan3 ?

Comment: Wait... what? If one of those is `null`, you want to call a method on them? It'll be `null`, you'll get a NPE!

Comment: Did you mean `if(trjmhn1 != null)`?

Answer (score 4):

With an `else`, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your logic.

```
    if (terjemahan1 == null) {
        return terjemahan1.get(0).getDayak();
    }            
    else if (terjemahan2 == null) {
        return terjemahan2.get(0).getDayak();
    }  
    else  {
        return terjemahan3.get(0).getDayak();
    }
```

I think you probably want the opposite though, so you only call this on variables that are not `null`. In this case you have to decide which one you want to call in preference if they are all not `null`. Also you have to decide what to do if all of them are null.

```
    if (terjemahan1 != null) {
        return terjemahan1.get(0).getDayak();
    }            
    else if (terjemahan2 != null) {
        return terjemahan2.get(0).getDayak();
    }  
    else if (terjemahan3 != null) {
        return terjemahan3.get(0).getDayak();
    }
    else
    {
       // decide what to do in this condition
    }
```

Comment: I think you want the last branch to be `terjemahan3`

Comment: hmm, condition terjemahan1 can be execute but condition terjemahan2 & terjemahn 3 can't execute...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your comment fully. Can you write out your requirements in full, in a list.